# AWS Security Group Creation NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a script that creates a security group(s) in AWS, it creates rules for ingress (inbound) and egress (outbound) traffic, my script looks like this right now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/*
This is a script to generate security groups and apply them to instances in a VPC.
Attached to this script is a json file which has the security group parameters in it.
Run this script by executing:

node AWS_Security_Groups.js
*/
'use strict';

process.env.AWS_PROFILE

var PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var properties = PropertiesReader('/Users/testuser/.aws/credentials');

AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId : properties.get('aws_access_key_id'),
        secretAccessKey : properties.get('aws_secret_access_key'),
        region : 'us-east-1'
})

var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'});
// Load credentials and set region from JSON file
//AWS.config.loadFromPath('/Users/testuser/.aws/credentials');
// Load in security group parameters
let securityParams = require('./securityParams.json');


module.exports = {
    //Exports creation of Security Groups
    createSecurityGroup: (req, res) => {
        ec2.createSecurityGroup(securityParams, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return (console.log("Error", err));
            }
            // Pass the Json as a parameter in this function
            ec2.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(securityParams, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    res.serverError(err, err.stack);
                } else {
                    res.ok(data);
                    console.log('Ingress Security Rules Created');
                }
            })
            // Pass the Json as a parameter in this function
            ec2.authorizeSecurityGroupEgress(securityParams, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    res.serverError(err, err.stack);
                } else {
                    res.ok(data);
                    console.log('Egress Security Rules Created');
                }
            })
        })
    }
  }
module.exports.createSecurityGroup();
```

My Json file looks like this:

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [],
            "Description": "My security group",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "203.0.113.0/24"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "GroupName": "MySecurityGroup",
            "OwnerId": "123456789012",
            "GroupId": "sg-903004f8",
        }
            {
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [],
            "Description": "My security group2",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "203.0.113.0/24"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "GroupName": "MySecurityGroup2",
            "OwnerId": "123456789012",
            "GroupId": "sg-903004f28",
        }]
}
```

However I can't get the script to execute properly. I keep getting an error saying unread character '/' in the JSON file. Does anyone know what I'm missing? Also, I want to be able update the script to read in the security groups and if the group already exists don't try and create it.

So this JSON seems to work to some extent: It doesn't create any rules, just creates the security group:

```
    [
  {
    "IpProtocol": "string",
    "FromPort": integer,
    "ToPort": integer,
    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
      {
        "UserId": "string",
        "GroupName": "string",
        "GroupId": "string",
        "VpcId": "string",
        "VpcPeeringConnectionId": "string",
        "PeeringStatus": "string"
      }
      ...
    ],
    "IpRanges": [
      {
        "CidrIp": "string"
      }
      ...
    ],
    "Ipv6Ranges": [
      {
        "CidrIpv6": "string"
      }
      ...
    ],
    "PrefixListIds": [
      {
        "PrefixListId": "string"
      }
      ...
    ]
  }
  ...
]
```

I have to update my script with the params: `securityParams[0].UserIdGroupPairs[0]`

Comment: Which function is yielding the error? Maybe you have to escape the `/` in the IpRanges array

Comment: I tried removing that, and it didn't make a difference. The create function is erroring. I don't think it's reading any part of the JSON correctly. Do I need to add `securityParams[0`] or something? Or maybe in the other functions specify `securityParams[0].IpPermissionsEgress[0]`?

Comment: According to [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html) it looks ok :/ that's really weird

Comment: Yeah thats where I got it from, but I wonder if the describe function is different than the create function as far as what params are needed? Also maybe the script just isn't reading it in correctly?

Comment: Do you know how I can at least check for the existence of a group by Name for example in an if statement, and just console log and skip if thats the case?